# AVFoundation, create images all video's frames while playing its audio

Tags: ios, avfoundation, frame, scenekit, frame-rate

at a bit of a loss here.

Basically, I need to create a frame server that will give my app an image of each frame contained in the video at said video's frame rate. I need to do this while also playing its audio.

I'll be using these frames as a texture source for certain geometries on an SceneKit

Have never used AVFoundation, any pointers, tutorials or suggestions are welcomed

Comment: To be honest, you would be better off making use of a 3rd party library that already does all this. It will take days of work just to get "something" and it would take weeks of work to get something with good performance.

Comment: @MoDJ, what do you suggest? dont know about any library for this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994913/what-player-can-be-used-to-play-transparent-video-in-xcode-for-playing-it-in-ipa/25550467#25550467

Comment: Also be aware that SceneKit > iOS 7.0 features the SKVideoNode built in class. It only works for simple use cases, but if that is all your app needs then it could be useful.

Comment: @MoDJ, already tried SKVideoNode, but it does not properly wraps a SCNSphere :S

Comment: Well, you might want to have a look at my blog post that covers how to use a movie as a general purpose OpenGL texture, Xcode proj included: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post7_load_opengl_textures_with_alpha_channel_on_ios/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very general question.

Since you've never used AVFoundation, the [AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW3) should be your first stop.

In particular, the [Still and Video Media Capture section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW17) shows how to set a delegate for the capture process.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, already onto it, basically want i'm looking for is using a video as the texture source for a scenekit geometry, AS IT PLAY in real time. lots of learning around here

Comment: thing is i dont want to apply texture from a capture device, but from a file on disk, have been trying with AVPlayer / AVPLayer to no avail thus far :S