# Overlaying Alpha Graphics in IOS (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm curious if anyone could potentially help me conceptualize the best, and most efficient, approach to accomplish an effect wherein a a video/image sequence is overlayed on top of a view.  The best example would be the stock Weather app on iOS.  A screenshot;

[image]

You can check out the animation [here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CUFasfD685I/UlirhgGC-GI/AAAAAAAAFXc/kL_QgiEN1g8/s1600/Weather+application+in+iOS+7.gif).  I've done some testing and have found that the easiest approach is to create my graphics with an alpha channel in After Effects, then export as a .png image sequence, and use the following code;

```
// Set the animation group
    myAnimation!.animationImages = [UIImage]()

    for var index = 0; index < 149; index++ {
        var frameName = String(format: "image_\(index)")
        myAnimation!.animationImages?.append(UIImage(named: frameName)!)
    }

    myAnimation?.animationDuration = 5.0
    myAnimation?.startAnimating()
```

The issue I keep facing is that, for a five second animation loop, I'm looking at 150 frames of content.  Creating these graphics at @3x and @2x resolutions, even with app thinning, is making my app bundle huge.  Additionally, and more importantly, appending 150 images to the array seems to create a fair amount of lag in playing the content.

If I were to build a weather app, like the example above, I'd also be looking at dozens of different weather conditions and would need hundreds of individual frames.

Are there better ways of going about this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using AVPlayer with an .mp4.  Video with low contrast (like the weather app) will help keep the size down and the impact minimal.

Comment: Awesome suggestion!  I was afraid to go this route since the video can't have an alpha channel, but in retrospect, it seems simplest to make multiple videos with the possible backgrounds and go from there.  I tried your suggestion and got my 149 frame clip down to 128KB in .mp4.  It looks great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An actual working and optimal solution for alpha channel videos in an iOS app can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16951869/763355). Keep in mind that if you compose multiple videos over multiple backgrounds that will inflate your app since each video takes up space in the download. No way around that. Also, decoding all that PNG image data on the fly will burn a lot of CPU.