# Animated overlay for videos on iOS

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, overlay

What's the common modern standard for animated video overlays? (e.g. if you want to add an animated logo to video recorded from the camera)

During research, I've found the following options:

- GIF - seems to be pretty outdated technology
- FLV - supports alpha-channel, but no longer supported by Adobe.
  Requires FFMPEG.
- PNG sequence - the downside of this is having multiple files for each
  frame.

What's the right format/technology to use?

Ideally, what is natively supported on iOS (doesn't require FFMPEG)?

Comment: Have you considered SVG (https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit)?

Comment: For a real solution that works natively under iOS, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16951869/763355

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overlay your custom video animation over video which user will be recorded I suggest to use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework which allow a lot video/photo customization's and different graphic effects. For example how to mix two videos: [nice article](http://indieambitions.com/idevblogaday/mixing-videos-gpuimage/). Also I suggest you to read article about [Chroma key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) which are something like standard of video/photo mixing. (because as I understand you just want make something like watermark?). GPUImage also has Chroma key filter which you can use in your purpose.

By default Apple supports h264 codec in mp4 container. So your video should be in this codec.
Hope I fully answered on your question

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add overlays using the AVFoundation framework supplied by apple itself. Speaking about the other ways such as GIF, FLV, they are not supported natively by APPLE which puts you out of luck.

Apple suggests various tools such as [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool) that lets you stitch the Core Animations and the videos together.

[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) is a link that explains how to add various effects such as 
Colored borders with custom sizes.
Multiple overlays.
Text for subtitles or captions.
Tilt effects.
Twinkle, rotate, and fade animation effects!

I am not sure how much of this is application for the application that wanted to add animations while recording. May be some one else could help in it. I hope this helps you about the native way to add animations in recorded videos in iOS.