# Playing prepared animation in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, animation

We have animations (approx. 6-7 seconds in 700x700 px, in transparent background) which are prepared by a design company.
I need to show these as an introduction in the beginning of our iOS app.
 What is the best way/format to use them easily in the app?
 I don't want to deal with animation details because they are all prepared by designers already.

We tried png sequences with `UIView`'s `animationImages` feature so far, but this approach wasn't memory friendly.

What do you suggest?

Comment: maybe use GIF? there are many GIF library out there

Comment: What format are the animations in? Or can you request any format? GIF or video might be the best way to go. You can fairly easily display either.

Comment: Yes, I can request any format. Background should be transparent btw, I'm editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Simple approach:

```
let timer = Timer()

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // I am using tiff image file  for animation.You can use png or jpg both will works...
    var imagesNames =  ["1.tiff","2.tiff","3.tiff","4.tiff","5.tiff","6.tiff","7.tiff","8.tiff","9.tiff","10.tiff","11.tiff","12.tiff","13.tiff","14.tiff","15.tiff"]

        var images = [UIImage]()

        for i in 0..<imagesNames.count{
            images.append(UIImage(named: imagesNames[i])!)
        }

        imageView.animationImages = images
        imageView.animationDuration = 2
        imageView.startAnimating()

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timeToMoveOn), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

**Note:** If you dont want the animation to be repeat.In timer function set **repeat** to **false**

```
     func timeToMoveOn() {    
     //Do you stuff here.After animation finished
        print("It Workes")
     }

     //To hide status bar.If you want to hide statusBar.
     override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
     return true
     }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I've already tried that, but it caused memory issues. My animation contains 100 frames, 700x700 each (total spritesheet is 1-2 mb), and the all images took over 150mb on memory (because of decompressed png). Is there something wrong on my implementation or is this normal?

Comment: i will update with alternative method for you.but 150mb is way too much.i recommend you to convert your png as  little as possible if they dont loose quality.thanks for letting me know.cheers

Comment: try this project from this link. it could be your solution https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Answer (score 0):

For a low memory usage implementation that supports a full alpha channel, have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16951869/763355). Note that just loading the uncompressed data with UIImageView and an array is not going to work since that will decompress all the data into memory and use up all device memory. What is nice about this approach is that it can encoded a full alpha channel into H.264 using a split RGB+Alpha encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find an easy well working solution. Using images will need tons of memory and from my experience with movies you won't get well working transparency.

Depending on your animation you can lower the resolution, remove some frames or if the transparent areas is in the edges you could crop the frames and put them on spritesheets and do a animation with that.

One tool to create spritesheets is https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/.

Answer (score 0):

I made some improvement on Joe's answer. Instead of loading all images into array, I read next image from xcasset on every iteration of `Timer` and don't keep a reference to previous images.

I debugged this code on real device (iPhone 5s), memory usage keeps groving while playing animations. When it reaches to 500-600mb, my app fires `didReceiveMemoryWarning()`, and memory suddenly drops to normal levels (iOS clears the previous image's caches I think). No performance problems and no crashes.

Is there any problem with that solution?

```
func startAnimation() {
    // 0.041 -> 24 fps (1/24 = 0.041)
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.041, target: self, selector: #selector(transitionPhotos), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func transitionPhotos() {
    if currentCount < frameCount {
        self.animationView.image = self.getNextImage(index: self.currentCount)
        currentCount = currentCount + 1
    } else {
        stopAnimation()
    }
}

func getNextImage(index: Int) -> UIImage {
    return UIImage(named: "\(fileName)\(index)")
}

func stopAnimation() {

    currentCount = 0
    if let timer = self.timer {
        if timer.isValid {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
    timer = nil
}
```